# Adding validation on selection to the user selected rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have this form where i collect data submitted by the user. The problem i have is quite simple but i don't know how to find the fix for it.

This form has multiple rows and each row gets saved to the db on submit. And i handle the data with a CakePHP backend. What is the proper method i validate this form? I can add the `required` attribute on the input fields but when i do that every input field needs to be filed with relevant data.

Is there a way where i can make it as when a user selects one row then that row will get the validation attributes so that entire row HAS to be filled with data? (Eg. User selects Row 1 "Select a shop" dropdown then the whole row has to be filled in order to submit the form.)

[image: Quotation Form]

**This is how my rows are structured**

```
        <div class="row txtMult">
            <div class='col-md-2 nopadding'>
                <div class='form-group nomarg'>
                    <select class="shop-name form-control select2" name="Quotationitems[0][shop_id]" style="width: 100%;">
                        <option selected="selected" >Select a Shop</option>
                        <?php
                        if (!empty($ShopsItems)) { 
                            foreach ($ShopsItems as $shop):        
                                ?> 
                                <option data-link="#<?= h($shop->id)?>" value="<?= h($shop->id)?>"><?= h($shop->shopname)?></option>
                            <?php endforeach;  } ?> 
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class='col-md-1 nopadding'>
                    <div class='form-group nomarg text-center'>
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success shop-value"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-info-circle"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class='col-md-2 nopadding'>
                    <div class='form-group nomarg'>
                        <select class="material-price form-control select2" name="Quotationitems[0][material_id]" style="width: 100%;">
                            <option selected="selected" >Select the Material</option>
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($MaterialItems)) { 
                                foreach ($MaterialItems as $material):        
                                    ?> 
                                    <option data-price="<?= h($material->unitprice)?>" value="<?= h($material->id)?>"><?= h($material->name)?></option>
                                <?php endforeach;  } ?> 
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='col-md-1 nopadding'>
                        <div class='form-group nomarg'>
                            <input type='number' id="width" name="Quotationitems[0][width]" min='0' class='form-control val1'>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='col-md-1 nopadding'>
                        <div class='form-group nomarg'>
                            <input type='number' id="height" name="Quotationitems[0][height]" min='0' class='form-control val2'>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='col-md-1 nopadding'>
                        <div class='form-group nomarg'>
                            <input type='number' id="sqft" name="Quotationitems[0][sqft]" min='0' class='multTotal form-control val3' readonly>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='col-md-1 nopadding'>
                        <div class='form-group nomarg'>
                            <input type='number' id="unitprice" name="Quotationitems[0][unitprice]"  min='0' class='form-control val4 material-total'>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='col-md-1 nopadding'>
                        <div class='form-group nomarg'>
                            <input type='number' id="amount" name="Quotationitems[0][amount]"  min='0' class='form-control val5'>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='col-md-2 nopadding'>
                        <div class='form-group nomarg'>
                            <input type='number' id="subtotal" name="Quotationitems[0][subtotal]" min='0' class='form-control multTotal2' readonly>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Create a function `validateRow()` then loop through all the rows and every time you find a selected row trigger the function for the row validation...

Comment: Understood. i'll give it a go and see. :D

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I used a validator library. Can you have a look? http://jsfiddle.net/hrvLoeko/ how can i target the first dropdown rather than targeting the input fields?

Answer (score -1):

I will explain to you the logic to achieve your goal:

1. By using JQuery [.focusin()](https://api.jquery.com/focusin/) on the `row` you will know which row has been selected (by the ***Event*** eventObject parameter)
2. Now you will activate an event on each `<input>` for that row (identified by `type` and `id` to distinguish what kind of data are you going to validate) such as [.keyup()](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/) or HTML attributes such as `required`, `maxlength` and so on...
3. Also enable a [.focusout()](https://api.jquery.com/focusout/) event on the `row` to check if all the fields are blank. In this case you have to remove all the previous set validation rules.

[Here there's your JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrMavin/yrwpp8Lh/)